# Outfile & Iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I am having a head-scratcher and need a human more intelligent than I to tell me where I am wrong/ what is going on.

All I am trying to do is open a file, read the number, add one to the number, truncate the file with my new number, and be done. The purpose is so that I can keep a memory even after my (other larger) program is shutdown. Each time I run the function it does weird stuff

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int getcount(){
   int number;
   ifstream indata;
   ofstream otdata;
   indata.open("count.txt");
   indata>>number;
   number++;
   otdata.open("count.txt", ios::trunc);
   otdata.close();
   return number;
}
int main()
{
   int i;
   i=getcount();
   cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

my current output looks like this

32575
32655
65536
65536
65536
32622

Is there a better way to do this? Where should I look? Did I typo?  I have done stuff just like this before and have read the documentation, my college books, etc, cant find anything revealing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're never writing to otdata

Comment: I knew it was something silly fml, long day. thanks Mat

Comment: @EuclideanDreams A little note: Don't open the file for reading and writing at the same time using two different streams. Not all OS:es will accept that. Windows will by default fail to open the second stream.

Answer (score 0):

Does count.txt exist? If it does, it looks like you're not storing the number after you've opened it (nothing that writes back the `number` between otdata.open and otdata.close). Also, you should close indata after you're finished reading it.

Comment: Yeah Mat told me about that(not writing data), I am just at the end of a long day lol, I took the indata.close(); out trying to debug earlier, but thank you for reminding me. thank you so much for the help. I just need to sleep lol.